# I want to typeset following matrix in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, matrices

I have a problem with following matrix. Actually I can't put this matrix in LaTeX.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The boxes drawn with TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  \check B \equiv
  \left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(tmp.base)]
        \node (tmp) {$B^L$};
        \path (tmp.north) ++(0,.3em);
        \draw[overlay]
          (tmp.south east) ++(.75em, -.5em) rectangle (tmp.north west)
        ;
      \end{tikzpicture}
      & 0 \\[.4em]
      0 &
      \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(tmp.base)]
        \node (tmp) {$B^R$};
        \path (tmp.south) ++(0, -.3em);
        \draw[overlay]
          (tmp.north west) ++(-.75em, .5em) rectangle (tmp.south east)
        ;
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{array}
  \right]
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Or a little larger:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  \check B \equiv
  \left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(tmp.base)]
        \node (tmp) {$B^L$};
        \path (tmp.north) ++(0,.3em);
        \draw[overlay]
          (tmp.south east) ++(.75em, -.75em) rectangle (tmp.north west)
        ;
      \end{tikzpicture}
      & 0 \\[1em]
      0 &
      \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(tmp.base)]
        \node (tmp) {$B^R$};
        \path (tmp.south) ++(0, -.3em);
        \draw[overlay]
          (tmp.north west) ++(-.75em, .75em) rectangle (tmp.south east)
        ;
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{array}
  \right]
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 9):

Some improvements to `@onewhaleid`'s tikz-free solution. I slighly modified some parameters and managed to get the brackets fully enclose the contents of the matrix:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{1.25em}
  \check B \equiv
  \begin{bmatrix}\noalign{\vskip0.5ex}
  \, \boxed{B^L} & \hspace{-2em} 0 \\[-0.8em]
  0 & \hspace{-1.85em}\boxed{B^R} \,\rule[-3.5ex]{0pt}{0pt}
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. I should have put my `\setlength` inside the `align` environment too.

Comment: For one row displays, use `equation`, not `align`.

Comment: @egreg: Oh yes, I forgot that. I took@onewhaleid's code as a starting point,  and focused on the problem of the brackets size. Thanks for pointing that.

Answer (score 7):

This is a non-tikz alternative, although I can't work out how to get the brackets the correct size.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

% increase padding around fboxes
\setlength{\fboxsep}{1em}

\begin{align}
\check B \equiv
\begin{bmatrix}
\, \boxed{B^L} & \hspace{-2em} 0 \\[-0.9em]
0 & \hspace{-2em} \boxed{B^R} \,
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For one row displays, use `equation`, not `align`.